# Null Pointer Exception when using a spinner in alertDialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner, android-alertdialog

This is the code I wrote:

```
// create a view in dialog box
final View fileView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.filename, null);
String[] array_spinner = new String[5];
array_spinner[0]="1";
array_spinner[1]="2";
array_spinner[2]="3";
array_spinner[3]="4";
array_spinner[4]="5";

Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_CAT);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
s.setSelection(2);

//Spinner mCAT = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_CAT);
//ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
//fileView.getContext(), R.array.a_CAT, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
//adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
//mCAT.setAdapter(adapter);

EditText mSID = (EditText) fileView.findViewById(R.id.et_SID);
EditText mSCD = (EditText) fileView.findViewById(R.id.et_SCD);
EditText mNUM = (EditText) fileView.findViewById(R.id.et_NUM);
final String tSID=mSID.getText().toString();
final String tSCD=mSCD.getText().toString();
final String tNUM=mNUM.getText().toString();

// show dialog box
new AlertDialog.Builder(CameraActivity3.this).setTitle("Set FileName")
  .setView(fileView)
  .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

      Toast.makeText(CameraActivity3.this, tSID+tSCD+tNUM, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }// public void onClick
  }) // setPositiveButton
  .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
```

However, I am receiving a **null pointer exception**. After some testing (commenting out some lines), it seems to be related to the spinner adapter. Did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) fileView.findViewById(R.id.sp_CAT);
```

Answer (score 2):

write below code line

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) fileView.findViewById(R.id.sp_CAT);
```

instead of

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_CAT);
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this in the future using `DialogFragment` to build the `AlertDialog`, you can't use just `this` in the `ArrayAdapter`. My solution is below:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_num_spinner_popup, null);

    builder.setView(myView);

    programNumbers = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.prog_num_spinner_list);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> numbersAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(), R.array.program_numbers, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    numbersAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    programNumbers.setAdapter(numbersAdapter);
```

I replaced `this` with `this.getActivity()` combined with Zaz Gmy's answer and Dipak Keshariya's answer (which are the same).